# Location of Meteor mobile-config.js file

Tags: meteor

This may be an easy question, but I am not sure if my mobile-config.js file is being loaded.

I am getting this error in the simulator:

```
ERROR whitelist rejection
```

And I read somewhere that I need to put:

```
App.accessRule('*');
```

in my mobile-config.js file.

But it doesn't seem to be working. Where should I put my mobile-config.js file?

Comment: it should be upload at the top lvl of the application, that means on the level of the /client and /server folder for example

Answer (score 1):

Create a **mobile-config.js** file in your project root folder and add access rules as needed:

```
App.accessRule('https://*.mycdn.com/*');
App.accessRule('http://pbs.twimg.com/*');
```

After building your app you can check rules were applied in *.meteor/local/cordova-build/config.hml* where they should be listed as acess tags with origin attribute:

```
<access origin="https://*.mycdn.com/*"/>
<access origin="http://pbs.twimg.com/*"/>
```